# Get percentage of activity for each hour of a day

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am new in python and I have some trouble with my dataframe.
I have a dataframe in python with a column datetime and others with activity counts, recorded for each hour of a day :

```
datetime, activity_a, activity_b, ... 
yyyy-mm-01 01:mm:ss, a11, b11
yyyy-mm-01 02:mm:ss, a12, b12 
yyyy-mm-01 03:mm:ss, a13, b13
...
yyyy-mm-02 01:mm:ss, a21, b21
yyyy-mm-02 02:mm:ss, a22, b22
yyyy-mm-02 03:mm:ss, a23, b23
```

I would like to retrive the percentage of activity by hour, with respect to the day :

```
datetime, activity_a, activity_b, activity_a_percentage, activity_b_percentage :
yyyy-mm-01 01:mm:ss, a11, b11, a11/(a11+a12+...), b11/(b11+b12+...) 
yyyy-mm-01 02:mm:ss, a12, b12, a12/(a11+a12+...), b12/(b11+b12+...) 
yyyy-mm-01 03:mm:ss, a13, b13, a13/(a11+a12+...), b13/(b11+b12+...) 
...
yyyy-mm-02 01:mm:ss, a21, b21, a21/(a21+a22+...), b21/(b11+b12+...) 
yyyy-mm-02 02:mm:ss, a22, b22, a21/(a21+a22+...), b22/(b11+b12+...) 
yyyy-mm-02 03:mm:ss, a23, b23, a21/(a21+a22+...), b23/(b21+b22+...)
```

where the denominator equals the total activity of the day in question, i.e. a11+a12+... is the sum of all activity_a for the day yyyy-mm-01.

Any idea to do that without iterating explicitly on the rows of the dataframe ?

For instance :

```
              datetime     a     b  
1  2021-01-01 01:00:00  1  3  
2  2021-01-01 02:00:00  1  4  
3  2021-01-02 08:00:00  1  2  
4  2021-01-02 09:00:00  3  1
```

expected output :

```
              datetime     a     b     a_percent     b_percent 
1  2021-01-01 01:00:00  1  3  0.5  0.43  
2  2021-01-01 02:00:00  1  4  0.5  0.57
3  2021-01-02 08:00:00  1  2  0.25  0.67
4  2021-01-02 09:00:00  3  1  0.75  0.33
```

Comment: Can you provide a relatively small dataframe input as an example, and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` to get totals columns, which you can then join onto your overall data frame and perform the calculation you are after.

The join will copy the total value for each day into a new column, repeating the total value for each row which is that day

I don't think you can do this all in one step

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import date
from datetime import time

data =[
    [date(2020,1,1), time(1,0,0), 1,3],
    [date(2020,1,1), time(2,0,0), 1,4],
    [date(2020,1,2), time(8,0,0), 1,2],
    [date(2020,1,2), time(9,0,0), 3,1],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['day', 'time', 'activity_a', 'activity_b'])

activities = ['activity_a', 'activity_b']

totals = df.groupby(by='day').agg({activity: 'sum' for activity in activities})

df=df.join(totals, on='day', rsuffix='_total')

for activity in activities:
    df[f'{activity}_percentage'] = df[activity] / df[f"{activity}_total"]
    df.drop(columns=[f"{activity}_total"], inplace=True)
```